# New files not being pulled (sourcetree)

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am developing an app with my friend.
My friend made a new branch named "develop".
As my friend modifies the file and adds new files on develop brach, I pull this.
All the modified files will be reflected on my local repository, but the new files won't be added.
Can anyone please help me what I should do to add the new files on my local repository?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am pretty sure that you are on the "develop" branch that your friend has created and not on your master (or whatever) branch. To go to the "develop" branch you have to do -

```
git checkout develop
```

If you are on that branch and you do a `git pull` then it would change everything in your local repo in accordance with the new branch. Check whether your friend has really added the files by running `git add .`. You can check that in github UI.